# How to get the dictionary (keys and values) from different function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary, key-value

Say i have a dictionary of:

```
def funcA():
    invdict = {{'fruits':{'apple','manggo'}},{'veggies':{'cabbage','cucumber'}},{'drinks:{'juice','coke'}}}
    return(invdict)
```

and i want to call the dictionary `invdict` along its keys and values to another function

```
def funcB():
    invdict = funcA()
    return invdict
```

main code is

```
def funcA()
def funcB()
print(funcA)
print(funcB)
```

Comment: I don't see a question in this question...? What are you trying to do that you are not already doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already left you a comment but I figured I'd put this in an answer to make it easier to read without the limitations of a comment.

There are a couple of problems here. Firstly, it appears you're trying to make a dictionary of lists, but you're using dictionary syntax (curly braces) for your lists instead of list syntax (square brackets) so instead of doing:

```
# this is wrong
invdict = {{'fruits':{'apple','manggo'}},{'veggies':{'cabbage','cucumber'}},{'drinks:{'juice','coke'}}}
```

You should do:

```
# this is right
invdict = {'fruits': ['apple','mango'], 'veggies': ['cabbage','cucumber'], 'drinks': ['juice','coke']}
```

You can also make this a lot easier to read with some appropriately-placed whitespace:

```
# easier to read
invdict = {'fruits': ['apple','mango'], 
           'veggies': ['cabbage','cucumber'], 
           'drinks': ['juice','coke']}
```

Now for the next problem. You want your function funcB to know about invdict, which is currently only available in the namespace of your function funcB. It looks like you're trying to return invdict from funcA but you're using return incorrectly. It also looks like you want to print the return values from these functions, but again, your syntax is incorrect (you're printing the function instance rather than calling it and printing its return value.) What you probably want to do is this:

```
def funcA():
    # correct syntax for a dictionary of lists, with whitespace for readability
    invdict = {'fruits': ['apple','mango'], 
               'veggies': ['cabbage','cucumber'], 
               'drinks': ['juice','coke']}
    # correct usage of return statement
    return invdict

def funcB():
    invdict = funcA()
    return invdict 

# correct way to call functions for their return values
print(funcA())
print(funcB())
```

remember, to call a function, you have to do function_name(). If the function takes parameters, the parameters go inbetween the parentheses. If it doesn't take parameters, you just use "()." If you just type the function name, you're passing the function definition itself, rather than executing that function (there is separate uses for this, but that's another story.)

Comment: the thing is, when i try to ask user an input in funcA for a dictionary, and return the items of dictionary and call it in funcB, it doesn't work. Maybe i should have posted my real code. I'm sorry. I'm just new in Python. Maybe i should delete this question later.

Comment: i can't post within 90 mins. how do i access the chat? i'm sorry, i'm just new to python pls bear with me.

Comment: try posting it on pastebin and just put a link in a comment

Comment: i'm just applying your suggested codes now... thank you for your time. If you see the codes, i initially applied calling it in the 2nd function but didn't work so i tried to call it on the main code outside the functions and still didn't work.

Comment: Your program seems to work fine (I am using python 2, however, so when I input data I have to put it in double quotes. It is very dangerous to use "input()" in python2, we are supposed to use "raw_input()" instead) The reason your program doesn't print anything is because when you call createPRICE() it clears the screen. I also noticed that you call createINV() twice, but you only save the dictionary the second time you call it.

Comment: yes. about that, i added the skip() next to calling createINV() so that i have to press any key before exiting. I also called createINV() twice so i'd know where it'd show up. But unfortunately, it didn't show up on either in the createPRICE() or outside the functions

Comment: In the code you uploaded to pastebin, you didn't call skip() after calling print(invdict). You call createPRICE() immediately after the print() call, which causes the screen to be cleared before you can see what you printed. If you comment out createPRICE() the program works

Comment: i'm sorry i forgot to mention that i updated the codes since i'm still currently working on it. but okay, i will try your suggestion. This is my new codes. https://pastebin.com/7t0sszHD

Comment: Your code seems to work fine on my end, although you're still calling createINV() twice and only printing the values the second time you call it. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Did the program worked on yours? it just keep bringing me back to 'Enter the number of inventories'

Comment: Yes it worked fine. It asked me for the inventories twice, and after I entered them the second time, it printed them and asked me to press enter to continue. I pressed enter and the program exited. Are you running the same code that you put on pastebin?

Comment: WHAAAT? Tried it and after it asked the second time, it printed. Oh my God. My brain hurts. Sorry for the extended comments. I love you. Have a wonderful and blessed day.

Comment: No problem :-) I made a slightly improved version of your script btw. I changed every instance of "raw_input" back to "input" so hopefully it works OK on python 3 (I'm not that familiar with python 3). Note this is still a procedural approach, and an object-oriented approach would probably still be better. https://pastebin.com/35Tbisq8 Notice that in this version I stuck the main code into a function called "main()". This is a standard convention dating back to the C days. It's also better to use descriptive names for things (create_inventory and inventory_dict are much easier to understand)

Comment: Also my version doesn't need you to enter the number of items in advance, it just lets you keep entering however many you want and you simply enter a blank value when youre finished

Comment: i see. so should i use descriptive names/variables when writing a code even it takes a bit longer to type? I guess you're right. Understanding the codes are much better than typing the codes faster. Thank you. It did work on Python 3. I now figured out why it asked the user to input twice. I'll take it from here. Thank you so much my brodah.

Comment: yes, it's one of the unwritten rules of python. "import this" for more info

Comment: I also recommend you buy or download a copy of the book "Programming Python: An Introduction To Computer Science" by John Zelle. It's a great book that will help you learn the basics of python (and computer science!)